# Error processing request: Mage registry key "_singleton/callforprice/observer" already exists

Tags: magento

```
There has been an error processing your request
Mage registry key "_singleton/callforprice/observer" already exists
```

Admin is not opening frontend is not opening what happend to my site?

```
Trace:
#0 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/app/Mage.php(224): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/app/Mage.php(478): Mage::register('_singleton/call...', false)
#2 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_App.php(1316): Mage::getSingleton('callforprice/ob...')
#3 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/app/Mage.php(449): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#4 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/includes/src/Mage_Core_Block_Abstract.php(292): Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#5 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#6 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('page/html', 'root')
#7 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('page/html', 'root')
#8 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#9 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/includes/src/Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#10 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/includes/src/Mage_Cms_Helper_Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#11 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/includes/src/Mage_Cms_Helper_Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#12 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#13 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/includes/src/Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#14 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/includes/src/Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#15 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/includes/src/BalkeTechnologies_StoreMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard.php(91): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/includes/src/Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front.php(172): BalkeTechnologies_StoreMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#17 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#18 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/app/Mage.php(685): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /home/chhabraa/public_html/beta/index.php(96): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

Error log record number: 591000213289

Comment: Please post a full stack trace of an error.

Comment: Meantime check log files too.

Answer (score 1):

This error shows up in **app/Mage.php** class in the method **register**.
You have somewhere in your code used this method to register the same key more than once.
If you check the method:

`public static function register($key, $value, $graceful = false)`

You must set the third parameter $graceful to be true so it doesn't throw an exception like this:

`Mage::register($key, $value, true);`

Comment: I am new to magento.. Is these are the files that I have to check? app/code/local/modulename/Model ???

Comment: Judging from your posted code, you are using the compilation option in Magento and the only local file I can see there is: public_html/beta/includes/src/BalkeTechnologies_StoreMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard.php check this file or do a global search in the /includes/src/ folder for the keyword: '_singleton/callforprice/observer'. Because of the compilation the system is using the classes in /includes/src/ not in app/code/local/